# Вызов и подключение программы на c++ из c#

Tags: c#, c++

Есть программа на c++, которая генерирует зашифрованное сообщение и выводит в файл и консоль.
Программа на c# должна эти данные выводить на winforms. Как их вообще связать? Т.е. вызвать шифратор сообщения на с++ из c#, подождать пока она посчитает и выведет данные, а затем на с# в winforms выведет ответ?

Comment: Доступны исходные тексты обоих программ, или только C#?

Comment: @Chorkov обеих программ

Comment: @kot_mapku3 самый простой вариант тогда вызвать метод, осуществляющий шифрование, на C++ из C# кода.

Comment: @sp7 такое вообще возможно?

Comment: Лучше переделать программу на C++ в dll, подключить его и из C# вызать соответствующий метод.

Comment: @kot_mapku3, да.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Лучше переделать программу на C++ в dll, подключить его и из C# вызать соответствующий метод.

#### C++

1. Запускаем Visual Studio .NET.
2. Создаём новый проект   File->New->Project.
3. Выбираем Visual C++ Project, На вкладке Templates->Visual C++, Выбираем “Win32 Project”.
4. Выбираем имя для проекта, например TestLib. Нажимаем OK.
5. В следующей форме выбираем Application Type: DLL и Empty Project.
6. Добавим в "Source File" New Item->C++ File.
7. Добавим код

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   extern "C"
   {
     double __declspec(dllexport) Add (double a, double b)
     {
       return a + b;
     }
   }
   ```
8. Компилируем.

#### C#

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("TestLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern double Add(double a, double b);
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var x = Add(25, 17);
            MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Способ лучше, но мы любим одну программу, а стоит придерживаться хорошего тона, поэтому, должно отметить ваш ответ верным, но добавьте чуть более подробную информацию о dll, прошу

Comment: @kot_mapku3 ели вы хотите делать так, то обратите внимание на 
 [вот этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8368411/6384980).

Comment: @CoddWrench просто это дополнительные затраты времени и гуглежа насчет создания dll, оба ответа хорошие

Comment: [Пошаговое руководство. Создание и использование библиотеки DLL (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms235636(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: @koshe да, я тоже видел, просто там нет примера использования из c#

Comment: просто хотелось бы увидеть пример использования данной конструкции из c#

Comment: А если типы данных отличаются? Нельзя же будет передать лист c# в dll

Comment: Отличный ответ. Чуток структурировал, выделил пошаговую инструкцию. Проверьте, что смысл сохранился.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Все в порядке, спасибо.

Comment: @kot_mapku3 API библиотеки должно формироваться из простых типов. Вот ответ на ваш вопрос: [Как передать С# коллекцию в С++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5102904/6384980)

Answer (score 7):

Есть вариант запустить консольное приложение из C# и считать вывод.

```
 Process p = new Process();
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

 // Перехватываем вывод
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 // Запускаемое приложение
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "example.exe";

 // Передаем необходимые аргументы
 // p.Arguments = "example.txt";
 p.Start();

 // Результат работы консольного приложения
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

 // Дождаться завершения запущенного приложения
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Информация взята из [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx) и [ответов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands).

Comment: Хм, т.е. запустить из с#, отправив данные, затем считать ответ и закрыть, верно? А как же с# поймет что данные вывелись?

Comment: Да именно так, передаем данные через аргументы. Консольное приложение должно само закрыться.  `StandardOutput ` это поток вывода, метод `ReadToEnd` дожидается завершения вывода и считывает "сразу" все.

Comment: Вариант рабочий, но самым правильным будет `переделать программу на C++ в dll, подключить его и из C# вызвать` -- см. комментарий от koshe

Comment: @CoddWrench, а в чём смысл использования и `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`, и `p.WaitForExit();`? Во-первых, если мы уже присвоили строку в переменную, то завершение процесса её никак не изменит. Во-вторых, может ли быть так, что stdout закончился, а процесс ещё жив?

Comment: @Qwertiy это правило: _открывая не забудь закрыть(дождаться закрытия)_. Да не изменит. Да может, основной поток может жить и без потока стандартного ввода/вывода, например если не может освободить ресурсы.